# How to generate statistics of a table and columns of a table in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any function available like Generate Statistics in Netezza to generate the column metadata (duplicates, unique values, min value, max value etc) in snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

No, not really.

You have the [`TABLES` View](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html) which contains size(storage) and number of rows,
but the rest of the information (including the [`COLUMNS` View](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage/columns.html)) is related to *schema* metadata and not *data* metadata.

On the other hand the table structure itself (aka [micro-partitions](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#what-are-micro-partitions)) contains table metadata that makes eg `MIN()` and `MAX()` functions very efficient.  Some of the table statistics may be cached globally (ie in the Cloud Services part of the [Snowflake architecture](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/intro-key-concepts.html))

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the question on stats gathering in Snowflake.  Some information:

1. During data loading (all DMLs like COPY, INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE),
   these stats are already automatically gathered by Snowflake on
   micro-partition level.
2. During query processing, these stats are automatically leveraged
   by our optimizer for query performance.
3. Automatic background
   service like automatic clustering service (if enabled for a given
   table) will also continuously and incrementally work on fine-tuning
   the clustering quality of a table with those stats.

All these auto-magic features happen without user manual intervention (hence why Snowflake is known as a self-tuning, simple to use, data warehousing platform).

Comment: OP wants to see the statistics though.  It can be useful to know if columns in a table are actually being used, for example.  Are they all null? Or do they contain multiple unique values, etc.